# JBOSS 5 LOG4J ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: log4j, jboss5.x

Am migrating my application to JBOSS5 from JBOSS4

I get the below exception while doing so

I did all to make it work, replaced with new log4j, tried without log4j, changed common-logging jar.

But still am facing this exception. Appreciate your help on this.

Also, in my project they are maintaing JARS in three folders for some purpose 1.) webapp/lib 2.) common/lib 3.) services/lib

Am pasting here list of jars in each folder here

1.) WEBAPP/LIB folder

```
03/08/2012  06:54 PM    <DIR>          .
03/08/2012  06:54 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           458,647 admin.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM            49,170 bootstrap.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM             5,956 channel.jfap.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           246,395 channel.tcp.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           303,805 channelfw.jar
03/01/2012  02:25 PM           188,671 commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM            31,909 commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
03/01/2012  02:23 PM            65,621 commons-io-1.2.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           245,274 commons-lang-2.3.jar
03/08/2012  06:54 PM            55,423 commons-logging.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           534,203 dom4j-full.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM         2,124,154 emf.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM            90,193 ffdc.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           802,494 freemarker-2.3.8.jar
03/01/2012  02:23 PM           892,456 ibmorb.jar
03/01/2012  02:23 PM         1,500,466 idl.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           411,400 j2cImpl.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           140,745 j2cIntf.jar
03/08/2012  03:17 PM           372,224 log4j.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           140,592 naming.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           318,980 namingclient.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           167,958 ognl-2.6.9.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           695,816 pmi.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM             3,246 pmirm-sib.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           331,712 quartz-1.5.0.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           450,121 ras.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           383,227 rsadapterspi.jar
03/01/2012  02:23 PM           445,493 runtime.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM            85,758 runtimefw.jar
03/01/2012  02:23 PM         4,148,686 sib.common.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           572,695 sibws.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM            12,628 struts2-api-2.0.5.jar
03/01/2012  02:23 PM         2,206,214 struts2-core-2.0.5.jar
03/01/2012  02:25 PM            13,909 struts2-sitemesh-plugin-2.0.5.jar
03/01/2012  02:23 PM            16,105 tcss-batch_1.0.jar
03/08/2012  03:12 PM            71,435 tcss-stub.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM            21,838 txClient.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM            53,565 txClientPrivate.jar
03/01/2012  02:25 PM           343,292 utils.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM         9,675,478 wccm_base.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM               354 websphere-jars.txt
03/01/2012  02:24 PM             5,799 wsexception.jar
03/08/2012  03:20 PM           139,889 XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar
03/01/2012  02:24 PM           448,273 xwork-2.0.0.jar
              44 File(s)     29,272,269 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  156,930,625,536 bytes free
```

2.) COMMON/LIB folder

```
03/08/2012  06:51 PM    <DIR>          .
03/08/2012  06:51 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/01/2012  02:11 PM           327,810 backport-util-concurrent-3.0.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM           610,790 c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM             2,686 c3p0-oracle-thin-extras-0.9.1.2.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM           174,535 commons-math-1.1.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM           534,203 dom4j-full-1.3.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM           243,457 ehcache-1.4.0.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM            50,626 ejb3-persistence-3.0.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM           338,447 hibernate-annotations-3.2.0.CR1.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM           338,447 hibernate-annotations.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM            97,570 hibernate-entitymanager-3.2.0.CR1.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM            97,570 hibernate-entitymanager.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM         2,112,010 hibernate3-3.2.0.cr2.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM         2,112,010 hibernate3.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM         4,498,893 icu4j-3_8_1.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM           143,792 jsch-0.1.34.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM             8,277 jsr107cache-1.0.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM         1,941,501 jython-2.2.1.jar
03/08/2012  03:17 PM           372,224 log4j.jar
03/01/2012  02:11 PM         1,545,954 ojdbc14.zip
03/08/2012  06:51 PM            70,516 tcss-stub.jar
03/08/2012  03:20 PM           139,889 XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar
```

3.) SERVICES/LIB folder

```
03/08/2012  06:53 PM    <DIR>          .
03/08/2012  06:53 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/01/2012  02:08 PM            62,983 activation-1.1.jar
03/01/2012  02:09 PM           248,639 annogen-0.1.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:22 PM           427,742 axiom-api-1.2.11.jar
03/05/2012  02:22 PM           159,057 axiom-dom-1.2.11.jar
03/05/2012  02:22 PM           122,415 axiom-impl-1.2.11.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM           689,180 axis2-adb-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM           179,618 axis2-adb-codegen-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            18,269 axis2-ant-plugin-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            96,876 axis2-clustering-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM           254,358 axis2-codegen-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM           147,166 axis2-corba-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            16,422 axis2-fastinfoset-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            27,739 axis2-java2wsdl-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            28,679 axis2-jaxbri-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM           741,267 axis2-jaxws-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            35,725 axis2-jibx-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            19,184 axis2-json-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM         1,040,584 axis2-kernel-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM           430,582 axis2-metadata-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            13,728 axis2-mtompolicy-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            89,063 axis2-saaj-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            33,739 axis2-soapmonitor-servlet-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            11,453 axis2-spring-1.6.0.jar
03/08/2012  03:07 PM           284,405 axis2-transport-all-1.0.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM           152,386 axis2-transport-http-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            16,106 axis2-transport-local-1.6.0.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            26,613 axis2-xmlbeans-1.6.0.jar
03/01/2012  02:08 PM           331,716 backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
03/01/2012  02:09 PM            46,725 commons-codec-1.3.jar
03/01/2012  02:09 PM            53,082 commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
03/01/2012  02:08 PM           305,001 commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
03/01/2012  02:08 PM           109,043 commons-io-1.4.jar
03/08/2012  06:53 PM            55,423 commons-logging.jar
03/01/2012  02:08 PM            12,232 geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.jar
03/01/2012  02:09 PM            28,804 geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
03/01/2012  02:08 PM           168,160 httpcore-4.0-beta1.jar
03/01/2012  02:08 PM           152,058 httpcore-nio-4.0-beta1.jar
03/01/2012  02:09 PM         1,335,669 jalopy-1.5rc3.jar
03/01/2012  02:08 PM            54,187 jettison-1.0-RC2.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM           407,900 jibx-bind-1.2.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM           128,520 jibx-run-1.2.jar
03/08/2012  03:17 PM           372,224 log4j.jar
03/01/2012  02:08 PM           388,864 mail-1.4.jar
03/01/2012  02:09 PM            34,750 mex-1.4.1.jar
03/05/2012  02:20 PM            34,162 neethi-2.0.5.jar
03/01/2012  02:08 PM            32,108 soapmonitor-1.4.1.jar
03/01/2012  02:09 PM           149,442 woden-api-1.0M8.jar
03/01/2012  02:09 PM           225,594 woden-impl-dom-1.0M8.jar
03/01/2012  02:08 PM           148,429 wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
03/01/2012  02:09 PM           520,092 wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar
03/08/2012  03:20 PM           139,889 XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar
              51 File(s)     10,608,052 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  156,930,625,536 bytes free
```

And here goes the real exception

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:264)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3783)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4413)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:798)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:601)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:307)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.<clinit>(FilterDispatcher.java:151)
    ... 81 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from this

```xml
<property name="filteredPackages">javax.servlet,org.apache.commons.logging</property>
```

to this

```xml
<property name="filteredPackages">javax.servlet</property>
```

inside file JBOSS_HOME/server/name/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/META-INF/war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml

Tell me if it resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for swift response. I tried this one and unfortunately it was not working :-(

Comment: This can be from some other reasons too:
- Did you try to remove commons-logging from your web app and use JBoss .jar instead ?
- You maybe included classes from xml-api which will causes problems with classloader and config files.

Try that and tell me if it works ;).

Comment: I took commons-logging from jboss5 and put that in my webapp. Also I removed also JAXB related jars, Xerces , Xalan jars (xml related jars). Despite doing all these i still get this error. Dont know wat am missing :-(

Comment: ChapMic, in my current project, they are maintaing jars in three different folders 1.) webapp/lib 2.) common/lib 3.) services/lib . Am attaching here, the list of jar files in each folder, so that u can help me out. Thanks

Comment: Chap, i have edited the post with the list of jars in each folders. Hope this would give u some idea and u would help me out :-)